# How do you configure Django 3 to work with MySql 5?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, migration, mysql5

I'm using Mac 10.13.6 and MySql 5.5 (can't upgrade at this time).  I have just created a skeleton Django (v 3.0.2)/Python 3.7 app and configured my database setting like so

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'sql_mode': 'traditional',
        },
        'NAME': 'maps_data',
        'USER': 'myuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

I have used pip to install the mysqlclient ...

```
(env) localhost:maps davea$ pip install mysqlclient
Requirement already satisfied: mysqlclient in /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.4.6)
```

However, when I attempt to run the initial migrations created for me, I get these errors I don't understand ...

```
(env) localhost:maps davea$ python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 74, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 209, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 315, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 239, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(6) NOT NULL)' at line 1")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 67, in ensure_schema
    editor.create_model(self.Migration)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 324, in create_model
    self.execute(sql, params or None)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 142, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 74, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 209, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 315, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 239, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(6) NOT NULL)' at line 1")

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 233, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 91, in migrate
    self.recorder.ensure_schema()
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/chicommons/maps/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 69, in ensure_schema
    raise MigrationSchemaMissing("Unable to create the django_migrations table (%s)" % exc)
django.db.migrations.exceptions.MigrationSchemaMissing: Unable to create the django_migrations table ((1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(6) NOT NULL)' at line 1"))
```

What are the right versions of Django and mysqlclient to use, or what else do I need to do to configure things properly?

Comment: You will have to upgrade your database to at least 5.6 or downgrade Django to at most 2.0.

Comment: Hi Dave, what did you do to make it work?

Answer (score 4):

MySQL 5.5 was dropped in Django 2.1. Here's the [changelog](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/releases/2.1/#dropped-support-for-mysql-5-5).

So the official answer would be to upgrade your old version of MySQL.

...That said, I had a migration fail mid-execution in production because of this, and I was able to resolve it using the following process:

1. Obtain the raw sql that the migration would run with `python manage.py sqlmigrate myapp 0015`

   - Where 'myapp' is the name of your app, and '0015' is the migration number you're trying to run.
2. Adjust the query as required.

   - In this case; replace occurrences of 'datetime(6)' with 'datetime'
3. Run the new query manually.
4. Tell django that the migration has been run manually by calling `python manage.py migrate myapp 0015 --fake`